# Can't retrieve input tags with HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone-8, html-agility-pack

I am attempting to scrape a random site for input tags.

So I need to write this in such a way that it will work with most sites.

Currently I have

```
void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{

    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument dom = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

    dom.LoadHtml(e.Result);

    var node = dom.DocumentNode.Element("html");

    var inputs = node.ChildNodes["body"].Descendants("input");
```

but this isn't working.

node returns with the data I want but inputs always turns out null.

When I do `node.ChildNodes["body"].Descendants().ToList();` I see entries named "`input`".

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, how did you check `inputs` value? How about `var inputs = node.ChildNodes["body"].Descendants("input").ToList()`?

Comment: Please update your sample showing code that "isn't working" and what exactly "turns out null" (as `Descendants` should be returning empty enumerable if it can't find anything to my understanding).

Comment: @har07 this produces a collection with nothing inside of it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the sample I provide does show the code that "isn't working" as I said, the results are null. Yes, a collection that returns empty and null inside.

Comment: @har07 I lied... the command you posted returns all the inputs. I am confused... Why does just adding toList() produce the list I want but without it it's null?

Comment: @har07 please make this an answer so I can check mark it also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, it's just the way you verified was wrong. All those `null` values in the screenshot doesn't indicate that the `IEnumerable<T>` is empty, you can try to call `inputs.ToArray()` or `inputs.ToList()` in watch window instead to verify the result.

Remember that `IEnumerable<T>` lazy-load the items until necessary, for example, until you iterate through, call `ToList()`/`ToArray()`, etc.